# How to point a WebSocket to the current server

Tags: javascript, ajax, websocket

I have a Jetty 8 server running (hopefully soon with websockets).

If I want to send some data to the server with an ajax call, I can do this:

```
$.ajax({ url: "ajax?a=getSomeData" });
```

In this scenario, if I connect to my server at `192.168.1.100`, the real url where it will get the data from, will be `192.168.1.100/ajax?a=getSomeData`, but if I connect to another server running the same software at `192.168.1.200`, the url will be `192.168.1.200/ajax?a=getSomeData`.

But if I want to accomplish the same thing using WebSockets, I cannot find how to do it:

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://www.example.com/');
```

Works. But I want something like a relative url:

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://sockets?a=getSomeData');
```

So that - like the ajax request - if I were connecting to my server at `192.168.1.100`, the url will be `192.168.1.100/sockets?a=getSomeData`, and if I connect to `192.168.1.200`, the url will be `192.168.1.200/sockets?a=getSomeData`.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Just build the URL yourself:

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://" + location.host + "/whatever");
```

The `location` object is a property of the `window` object, and is therefore globally available.

To get only the host without the port, use `location.hostname` instead. If the websocket server listens on another port for example.

You can also inspect `location.protocol` to know if you should connect to `wss` (when `https` is used) or `ws` (when `http` is used).

Comment: Make sure you trim the port number off of `location.host` if you need to change it! `location.hostname` will work instead.

Comment: Just use `new WebSocket(location.origin.replace(/^http/, 'ws') + "/whatever")` to work with both http and https.